# Create an auto-installer using curl and how to pass the args?

Tags: bash, curl

`rvm` installer uses curl to install rvm. Copy from `rvm` official website, the command is
`curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=enabled [--ruby] [--rails] [--trace]`.

Getting the idea from this, I want to create an auto-installer using curl as well. This is my installer script fetch.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Copyright Ciel 2014

FLAG=$@
echo 'FLAG has been set to -ns '$FLAG
git clone --recursive https://github.com/imwithye/dotfiles.git ~/.dotfiles
cd ~/.dotfiles
./install.sh $FLAG
```

And I try to install my program via `\curl -sSL http://dot.ciel.im | bash $FLAG`(http://dot.ciel.im points to my fetch.sh script).  As you can see, I want to pass the args $FLAG from curl command to fetch.sh script, but it failed.

Does anyone know how can I pass the args from curl command `*** | bash $FLAG` to the installer script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is :

```
echo "$(curl -sSL http://dot.ciel.im)" | bash -s FLAG1 FLAG2 etc
```

The `echo` with quotes is important for not being interpreted as a single line.  Then, the `bash -s` allows you to add arguments to the script `bash` is executing.

you can also add `-x` to debug and see what commands are called and with which parameters.

```
echo "$(curl -sSL http://dot.ciel.im)" | bash -x -s FLAG1 FLAG2 etc
```